# Translate PHP String Functions to Javascript / jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, substr, strpos

This is the PHP code I'm trying to translate into Javascript / jQuery.  Any ideas?

```
$root_folder = 'es';
$url = "http://domainNamehere.com/event/test-event-in-the-future/";

$p = strpos($url, '/', 8);
$url_new = sprintf('%s/%s/%s', substr($url, 0, $p), $root_folder, substr($url, $p+1));
```

Comment: You may find the [`php.js`](http://phpjs.org/) project helpful for these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var root_folder = "es",
    url = "http://domainNamehere.com/event/test-event-in-the-future/",
    url_new = "",
    path_finder = /^(((http)s?:)?\/\/[^\/]+\/)/i;

url_new = url.replace(path_finder, "$1" + root_folder + "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strpos() ~ .indexOf()
substr() ~ .substring()
sprintf() ~ +
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP.js](http://phpjs.org/) offers ports of many common PHP functions to JavaScript.